# Count in 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I need to count how many times a result is found in 2 mysql column.

Ex.

```
|   Name      |    Fruit    |
|   John      |    Apple    |
|   Bill      |    Banana   |
|   Sam       |    Lemon    |
|   Sam       |    Kiwi     |
|   Bill      |    Banana   |
|   John      |    Apple    |
|   Bill      |    Pear     |
|   Bill      |    Pear     |
|   Bill      |    Pear     |
```

I need to get this result:

```
|   Name    |    Fruit   |   Count   | 
|   John    |    Apple   |     2     |
|   Bill    |   Banana   |     2     |
|   Bill    |    Pear    |     3     |
|   Sam     |    Kiwi    |     1     |
|   Sam     |   Lemon    |     1     |
```

I can't understand how it can works with 2 columns

Comment: Use `select name, fruit, count(*) from your_table group by name, fruit`

Comment: @RadimBača You should submit this as an answer instead of a comment on the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to use a `group by` clause like:

```
Select Name, Fruit, Count(*) as Count
from table
group by Name, Fruit
```

Comment: Thanks, all is fine now, just needed to use group by

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, I'd appreciate if you accept my answer as the correct answer by clicking the "tick" on the left of the answer @Edgars